# drupal user interested terms

Tags: drupal, tags

hi i'm using drupal 6. In my user page i want to show latest activities related to user interest. interest means ***terms*** that user participated (forum topics, articles, polls..). Can any one know the best way to do it.

For ex : stackoverflow shows questions related user participated tags.

Comment: Are you willing to create a module for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like something you might be able to do using the Flag terms module (http://drupal.org/project/flag_terms). This is a module that complements the much acclaimed Flag module (http://drupal.org/project/flag_terms), by allowing you to flag certain taxonomy terms. You can use views (http://drupal.org/project/views) to display lists of user flagged content.